# Rails: Font Awesome doesnt download

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-rails, font-awesome

I just run `bundle update` in my project, and Font-Awesome doesn't work anymore.

I tried both font-awesome-sass-rails and twitter-bootstrap-rails (which includes font awesome too), and I had the same behavior in both of them: instead of the icons, a square is shown.

I check the compiled CSS, and tried to download the fonts:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  src: url(/assets/fontawesome-webfont.eot);
  src: url(/assets/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"), url(/assets/fontawesome-webfont.woff) format("woff"), url(/assets/fontawesome-webfont.ttf) format("truetype");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

So I tried to download myapp/assets/fontawesome-webfont.woff, and it worked.
I just can't understand what's the problem here.

My `application.css.scss`:

```
*
 *= require_self
 *= require bootstrap-datepicker
 *= require_tree .
 */

@import "bootstrap";
body {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
@import "bootstrap-responsive";
@import "font-awesome";

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Pontano Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Pontano Sans'), local('PontanoSans-Regular'), url(/assets/pontanosans.woff) format('woff');
}

*{
  font-family: 'Pontano Sans', sans-serif !important;
}

.table tbody tr:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

// rest of file...
```

The pontano-sans, for example, work just as expected.

My Gemfile (just the assets group):

```
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass'
  gem 'font-awesome-sass-rails'
  gem 'libv8', :platforms => :ruby
  gem 'therubyracer', '>= 0.11.1', :require => 'v8', :platforms => :ruby
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'turbolinks'
  gem 'mousetrap-rails'
  gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
  gem 'spinjs-rails'
  gem 'ajaxspin'
  gem 'chosen-rails'
  gem 'jquery-rails'
  gem 'turbo-sprockets-rails3'
  gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'
end
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

---

EDIT!

Looks like a bug: https://github.com/littlebtc/font-awesome-sass-rails/issues/22

Comment: It used to work and it stopped suddenly after `bundle update`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is a [bug](https://github.com/littlebtc/font-awesome-sass-rails/issues/22).

For now I'm using my own fork of the repository.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest to change the approach : create a new directory under `app/assets` , named `fonts`. Then copy the glyphs images there and include it to the assets in `application.rb` file , like this :

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")
```

After that , you should rename your `font-awesome.css` to `font-awesome.css.scss.erb` and change the `@font-face` declaration in it like this :

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  src: url('<%= asset_path('fontawesome-webfont.eot')%>');
  src: url('<%= asset_path('fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix')%>') format('eot'), url('<%=    asset_path('fontawesome-webfont.woff')%>') format('woff'), url('<%= asset_path('fontawesome-webfont.ttf')%>') format('truetype'), url('<%= asset_path('fontawesome-webfont.svg#FontAwesome')%>') format('svg');
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
 }
```

This solution includes removing the gem `'font-awesome-sass-rails'` .

Answer (score 0):

Bug and [here](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/issues/139#issuecomment-14686906) are the reason of this.
Try to use

```
@import "font-awesome.css";
```

instead of

```
@import "font-awesome";
```