# Implementing bootstrap theme from wrapbootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, themes

I've downloaded a theme through wrapbootstrap but cannot figure out how to implement it. I assumed it was going to be just copying over the CSS and JS files but there seems to be much more to it.

The theme I have downloaded is https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/awesome-admin-WB0663265

I have temporarily uploaded it onto Github here <strike>github.com/raycchan/temp</strike> (i'll remove this ASAP once I resolve it)

There are example templates here that have the generated .html file as well as the .html.erb files, and once I plug the erb files into my rails app it throws out errors like the ones below:

But it doesn't recognize these:

```
<%= data.page.title || "Bootstrap Admin" %>         # data undefined
<%=partial 'dashboard-navigation'%>                 # partial undefined
```

Could someone instruct me step by step how to implement this bootstrap theme?
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is really interesting to give a Rails soul to the nice template . A few simple steps:

- copy .css to `app/assets/stylesheets` and .js to `app/assets/javasripts`
- include the new files in the manifest files `application.css` and `application.js`
- for font-awesome use [this description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247811/rails-font-awesome-doesnt-download/14248517#14248517)

Then share the result with us .

Comment: thanks. my problem is in addition, i'm getting thrown errors when i straight up use .html.erb as instructed for example here: https://github.com/raycchan/temp/blob/master/source/blog.html.erb

Comment: I think the call "partial" is wrong , if you'd like to render a partial , it should be `<%=render 'dashboard-navigation'%>`. The title error is probably missing helper , defining the page title.

Comment: hmm that's what I thought. But then theres a bunch of other stuff like the 'data' variable - I would assume it should be self contained and declared somewhere??

Comment: Exactly , those <i>'s are tags for glyphs , which you should place in an assets/images directory .

Comment: looks like it was due to some helper functions from 'middleman' - otherwise the rest works great. thanks for the help