# app not finding wrapbootstrap js and images files

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

After installing a Wrap bootstrap theme into my rails app by following the steps in a previous [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762660/implementing-bootstrap-theme-from-wrapbootstrap%20%22stackoverflow%20post); my app is not able to find my stylesheets and javascript files.  All of the files are under their respective directories under "BV_main/app/assets".  I'm getting the error:  *Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (not found)*.  Also the app is looking for my application.js file but I don't have one created, is that needed?  Can anyone offer any guidance?

**Application.html.erb file:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>BV</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag  'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %> 
 <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
 <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

**Application.css File:**

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css,    which will include all the files
* listed below.
*
* Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
* or any plugin's vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced   here using a relative path.
*
* You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
* compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles     defined in any styles
* defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
* file per style scope.
*
*= require_tree .
*= require_self
*/
```

**Errors from Inspect/Console:**

[image]
[image]

**JS Files location:**

/Users/user/code/BV_main/app/assets/javascripts

**CSS Files location:**

/Users/user/code/BV_main/app/assets/stylesheets

**Fonts Files location:**

/Users/user/code/BV_main/app/assets/fonts

**The index file location is with my welcome controller's views:**

```
welcome git:(layout) ✗ pwd
/Users/user/code/BV_main/app/views/welcome
✗ ls -ltr index.html.e*
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff   1015 Feb 29 20:10 index.html.erb_old2016003
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 user  staff  25044 Mar 13 13:41 index.html.erb
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of app/stylesheets/application.css

Comment: Thanks just added it

Comment: So the weird thing is that the the 404 locations are wrong.  It should be looking in /assets/ - not in stylesheets or javascripts, based on what you've provided, I don't see why it's doing that.  Did you make other changes to the asset pipeline?

Comment: I was wondering about that @trh, thanks.  No I don't believe I made any other changes to the asset pipeline....

Comment: I do have the index file under my welcome controller.  Would that affect where it is picking up my js and image files even if by default it should check under the assets/ pipleline?
/Users/user/code/BV_main/app/views/welcome

Comment: Heh, if you mean the index file from wrap bootstrap - you should absolutely move that out of the way :)

Comment: Yes it is.  Where should I move that too within the rails app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two issues that caused this issue that is now resolved by following the steps below.

1. The location for the images were not going to the exact location.  Therefore I used the Rails Asset tag to fix this issue by looking for the files in the correct asset pipeline location:

From:

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="images/humanity-logo.png" alt="" />
```

To:

```
<%= image_tag('humanity-logo', class: 'img-responsive') %>
```

2. I was missing the application.js file which is needed as it was not able to use jquery.  So I created a application.js file with just the following entries below:

   `//= require jquery`

   `//= require_tree .`